# Visual studio source control (VSS) not allowing all functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution that is source controlled in Visual Source Safe 2008.  On my laptop, if I right click on ony of the VS classes, I get 5 source control-related options (Check out for Edit, Get latest Version, Compare, Get, View History) which all work fine.

However, I have a new user who is supposed to have the same setup, but on her laptop's install of Visual Studio the only Source Control option she gets when right-clicking on a class is "Check out for Edit".  She can obviosuly check in the code too, but can't "view history" or "Get latest version" in Visual Studio.  She **does** have these options in Visual SourceSafe.

I', wondering what I need to do to get these options setup in her version of Visual Studio.  I've checked the Tools-->Options-->Source Control-->Advanced Settings and all of these settings are the same as mine, so I'm not sure what I could be missing.

I've tried searching and can't find where anyone has this same problem.  I'm guessing I'm missing something easy but can't quite figure out what it would be.  Any ideas would be much appreciated, but I cannot upgrade either VS or VSS (it's a large coproration, upgrades get done when IT says so, not whe I say so :-( lol)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that her solution is not connected to the VSS Server. You can let her go to Visual Studio File->Source Control->Change Source Control and check the connection status there.